# jQuery .attribute for p tags in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add an attribute of 'data-class' to every paragraph in an HTML element, the `'data-class'` should be set to the value of the `class`. I have used `.attr` but not able to assign the same value.
There are currently 9 paragraphs on the page with a numbered class of

> p1, p2, p3 etc...

How would I just set the data-class to the same p-tag as well?

I have jQuery like this so far:

```
$('p').attr('data-class', 'p'}
```

Comment: Why not just use the `class` attribute instead?

Comment: Yes it works, but I need the data-class to be equalled to the p-class currently the p class is also applied to the other p tags instead of data-class = p2, p3, p4 etc..

Comment: Your question would be clearer with some HTML for context. Preferably a [MCVE] of what you have tried so far. Are you just concerned with data or are you using the attribute as a styling hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over each `p` element with [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), setting the `data-class` attribute to the value of the `class` attribute (inspect the elements after running the snippet to see the change):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-class', $(this).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">P1</p>
<p class="p2">P2</p>
<p class="p3">P3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>P1</p>
<p>P2</p>
<p>P3</p>
<script>
$(function(){
    // $('p').attr('data-class', 'p');
   //This will attach a new attribute o you dom element and that you can visible in  when in you inspect.
or 
     $('p').data('class', 'p');
     // This may not visible in dom.
     console.log($('p').data('class'));
     // Dynamic creation
     $('<p />').data('class', 'p').appendTo('body');
     // Append with loop
     const data = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3'];
     $('p').each((index,element)=>{
           console.log(index,element)});
           $(element).data('class', data[index]);
     });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.each(fn(index, element){})`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate and set the value indiviually.

```js
$('p').each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).attr("data-class", "p" + (index+1));  
  //or
  //$(this).attr("data-class", "p" + $(this).index());  
  
  //For Demonstartion 
  $(this).text("p" + (index+1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

---

As an alternative [`.attr(key, func)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) can also be used.

```js
$('p').attr("data-class", function(index, element) {
  var v = "p" + (index + 1);
  //For Demonstartion 
  $(this).text(v);

  return v;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try it

```
var data_class = "value";

$("p").each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr("data-class", data_class);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data_class = "value";

$("p").each(function(index) {
    $(this).setAttribute("data-class", data_class);
});
```